# Visual Studio 2015: how to "Get Latest Version" only for projects belong solution

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, getlatest

I'm experiencing a strange behavior of Visual Studio 2015 connected to Team Foundation Server 2010 when "get latest version" of solution.

**When I perform "get latest version" of solution, Visual Studio 2015 will get all source controlled files and folders of Team Project, also if they don't belong to solution**; probably due to I have solution in the root of Team Project of TFS.

I didn't experienced that issue with Visual Studio 2010.

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
I have the following solution tree in TFS (I mention only files and folders belong to solution):

- Team Project root

  - MySolution.sln
  - Folder1

    - Folder1.1 with .csproj
    - Folder1.2 with .csproj
  - Folder2

    - Folder2.1 with .csproj
    - Folder2.2 with .csproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce  your situation with my side. However, I think this is the **correct** behavior.

Cause you didn't get the files only related to this solution, you just get the latest for the folder of the solution. This will definitely get other items they don't belong to solution but under the same folder of `.sln` file. VS will use this method to determine whether a file belongs to the corresponding sln.

Suggest you do not use this kind of folder architecture. When you create project, you'd better to check "**create directory for solution**" under root folder of team project.

[image]

Comment: Give a try with right click the .sln file  and the folders in **Source Control Explorer** and get latest. This will only get selected files and folders. Maybe this should be the workaround.

Comment: I solved with you suggestion, by putting solution file inside a dedicated folder and keeping other files and folder in their position. Thanks a lot!